# Shipping methods does not appear for different countries

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping-methods

I use magento 1.9.0.1 CE

It works correctly in France, and I am trying to make shipping for different countries.

For France we use Extension So Colissimo, and for other countries we have installed Owebia 2.

We have already created the grid of shipping fees for different countries based on the weight of the product in Owebia 2 and it seems that it works, but only for France.

Because in Owebia we have also created shipping fees for France, so when we have country France chosen both appears, So Colissimo and Owebia 2.

If we choose other country like Germnay, Belgium, Italy end so on, all shipping methods disapears, so methods from So Colissimo are removed (and that is OK) and also all the methods for Owebia 2, that should appear for Germany, Italy, Belgium etc.

Normally I have checked in System / Configuration / General /,

**Countries options**

Allow Countries :

- Germany
- Italy
- Belguim
- etc

Are selected, I do not know where else I can check to activate those methods of shipping for other countries than France.

Is there anyone who had the same problem? Or how can I correct it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution for this problem was the weight of the products.

Product were set with the weight in gramms, and Owebia was taking into account the same weight but in kilos.

so owebia thought that the weight of the product was 1500 KG and not 1.5 KG

So I have changed setting for shipping methods in owebia, and right now it works like a charm.

Maybe it will help to someone.